# How to store data as type number in mongodb using sails.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sails.js

> Problem : How to store data as type number in mongodb using sails.js

I am storing some record in mongodb using sails.js

name as string
mobile as number, i'm converting mobile from sting to number as

```
mobile = parseInt(mobile)
```

Model Definition

```
    mobile : {
      type: 'number',
      unique: true,
    }
```

It should looks like

```
{
  "name":"abc",
  "mobile":123456789 // Number
}
```

But after inserting record it looks like this as mobile type is double

```
{
  "name":"abc",
  "mobile":123456789.000000 // Double
}
```

How to convert mobile value form string to integer value ie. number in mongodb.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you not saving mobile number as a string ? Why you need number for it ?

Comment: Generally mobile number type is number so i want to store in number format in mongodb and also to compare strictly

Comment: even i have the same issue. I have tried to save a phone# like `9857415630` using Node+ mongoose and when i see it in Mongodb, it is saved as `9857415630.000000`

Answer (score 0):

you can convert it as NumberLong("2090845886852") and u can save it will covert it as 64bit integer.it works only for mongoshell